# Proving ZF-Axioms from Hereditarily Finite Axiom

Tags: set-theory

in the lecture notes on the set-theory lecture I'm attending at the moment i found the following exercise: 
Starting only from

Existence: $\exists x\forall y \neg y\in x$

Extensionality: $\forall x \forall y (\forall z(z\in x \leftrightarrow z\in y)\rightarrow x=y)$

Pairing: $\forall x\forall y \exists z \forall w (u\in z \leftrightarrow u = x \vee u=y)$

Union: $\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \leftrightarrow \exists w (w \in x \wedge z \in w ))$

together with the Induction-Principle
$(\varnothing \in B \wedge (\forall x\forall y(x\subseteq B \wedge y\in B \rightarrow x\cup \lbrace y\rbrace \in B)))\rightarrow B=V$ for every Term B and the Universe $V=\lbrace x \vert x=x\rbrace $

prove all other ZFC-Axioms except infinity and prove $\neg Inf$.

I managed to prove Foundation:

Let A be a Term and assume $\forall x \in A A\cap x \neq \varnothing $. In particular $\varnothing \not\in A$.  Let $B=V\backslash A$. Let $x\subseteq B$, $y\in B \implies x\cap A = \varnothing \implies x \in B$. Now consider $x\cup y$. We have $(x\cup \lbrace y\rbrace )\cap A= x\cap A \cup \lbrace y\rbrace \cap A = \varnothing \implies x\cup\lbrace y\rbrace \in B \implies B=V$

But I really don't know how to do the other axioms.
Are there any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Capital letters stand for classes, not for sets?

Comment: Yes, sorry, A and B are arbitrary Class-Terms, V is the Universe $\lbrace x|x=x\rbrace$

Answer (score 0):

The remaining axioms are generally of the form $\forall x.\mathit{something}(x)$, and you would prove them by induction on $x$, adding one element of it at the time.

For example, for Replacement you would have a functional formula $F(a,b)$, and you would then apply your induction axiom to the class
$$  B = \{ x \mid \{ b \mid a\in x\land F(a,b) \} \text{ exists} \} $$
In the induction step you already know that $p=\{b\mid a\in x\land F(a,b)\}$ exists and must show that $q=\{b\mid a\in(x\cup\{y\})\land F(a,b) \} $ also exists. But $q$ is just $p\cup\{b\}$ where $b$ is the (assumed unique) element such that $F(y,b)$, so it does exist.

Comment: I think the version of HF you have in mind is where x is an element of B and indeed in this case most of it gets quite simple, but here the axiom assumes x to be a subset of B which makes working with it much harder.

Comment: @Takirion: Yes, I didn't quite see that. How sure are you that that's not just a typo in your source? The premise "$x\subseteq B\land y\in B$" would be nothing more than a roundabout way to write "$(x\cup\{y\})\subseteq B$", so your variant of the axiom just has the premise $z\subseteq B\to z\in B$ for any nonempty $z$.

Comment: Worse yet, your version of the axiom is actually provable in ZF (meaning that if you succeed in proving $\neg$Inf from it, you will have uncovered an inconsistency in ZF): Suppose $B$ is a class that satisfies the premise but is not $V$. Then there is an $x\in V\setminus B$ _of minimal rank_. This clearly cannot be $\varnothing$ so there is an $y\in x$. But then, because of the minimality of $x$, we have $x\subseteq B$ and in particular $y\in B$, so by the assumption $x\cup\{y\}=x$ is in $B$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, so obviously this is a typo. So i will just write to my lecturer and ask him to correct it. Thank you